# Deriving time complexity of a function

Tags: java

This following program is for searching two dimensional square array of positive integers with sorted rows and columns in non-decreasing order. The program returns true if target (value) element exist in array, false otherwise.
I need to design algorithm for this task which will be as efficient as possible. 
I wrote this code, but i do not know how to derive the worst case run time complexity function using summations. I assume that the my solution is order O(n) in the worst case. but i do not know how to show it mathematically (using summations and etc).

Comment: This code doesn't make a lot of sense.  The `x==0` and `y==n-1` tests are redundant; you're already testing for them in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the actual code aside, your worst case is probably a two-dimensional array with one of the dimensions only being of size 1, so like an array with 100 columns and 1 row.  Then if you want the largest number, it's order N of the total number of elements in the array to walk to the end.

Answer (score 0):

On every iteration, either `x` decreases or `y` increases.  In the worst case, we don't terminate the loop until `x == 0` and `y == n-1`.  Therefore, we've walked from top-right (assuming we start at `x == n-1` and `y==0`) to bottom-left.

Assuming the array is `n`-by-`n` in size, then this will require `2n` iterations, worst-case.  Therefore, this is `O(n)`, worst-case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we're talking *upper* bounds (that's what O(*f*(N)) measures) so we're talking worst case scenarios. Which means traversing the whole array.

If we examine the algorithm, we see that it traverses a path across the array with no backtracking: `x` is never increased, `y` is never decreased, and we never spin on one spot. That means that the time cost will be linear in the sum of the dimensions of the array: O(N+M). For a square array (or any array where either dimension is a fixed multiple of the other) that simplifies to O(N) through constant-factor removal.

Showing it using summations… well, without loss of generality you're going to do a bunch of across steps followed by a bunch of down steps (or some reordering of them) which gives you a cost of:

K<sub>across</sub>×N<sub>across</sub> + K<sub>down</sub>×N<sub>down</sub> + K<sub>post</sub>

(that's pretty trivial). But all those constant K<sub>blah</sub> bits drop out in big-Oh analysis giving you O(N<sub>across</sub> + N<sub>down</sub>), which simplifies to O(2×N) for square arrays (with slightly different values for other shapes) and hence to O(N). You only get other cost functions when one of the dimensions is a super-linear function of the other, but that's rather exotic.

The key insight to deriving the cost function is knowing that you must traverse the whole array, yet you are just taking a ([Manhattan-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)) path across it and not visiting every cell.

Comment: "upper bounds" != "worst case".

Comment: @Oli: You're claiming that the worst case isn't an upper bound? That's… novel. After all, if the upper bound is larger than the worst case then there must (by construction) be a case _worse_ than the worst case, which is impossible…

Comment: I'm claiming that big-O does not imply "worst-case".  You can have big-O best-case complexity, big-O average complexity or big-O worst-case complexity.

Comment: Or the upper bound is less than the worst case, which is even more ludicrous.

Comment: @Oli: Upper bounds are worst cases (for cost functions). _However_, it is possible to impose extra side conditions which alleviate this (e.g., that “good” pivots are usually selected when doing a quicksort) though those side conditions should always be stated.

Comment: Not that it matters with this problem: here they are one and the same, and we're just measuring the length of the diagonal using an l1 norm.

Comment: Big-O notation refers to an upper bound, but not in the sense that you mean (so far as I can make out).  If I say that `T(n)` is in `O(n)`, that simply means that `T(n)` is (asymptotically) upper-bounded by `k.O(n)`.  But that's distinct from establishing that `T(n)` is an upper bound on the algorithm's runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Since a multi-dimensional array is really another form of a one-dimensional array (where n = x*y), this is in the order of O(n). The total number of elements it will search is going to be less than that, but only by a fractional amount. Even if it's a large fraction, this is stil thought of as O(n).

Start by figuring out your worst case scenario. This would be something like x+y+x or 2x+y.

Comment: If `n` is the total number of elements in the array, then this function is `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: Your worst case would be that the program traverses the entire first set in the outer array, then climbs up the inner and has to then find the first element of the last inner array. You can then show how this is 2x+y, you have to do this using some non-mathematical language.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I don't see that. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @Godwin: On every iteration, you either step left or down.  Assuming you start in the top-right, the worst case is you don't terminate until you reach bottom-left, which takes 2.sqrt(n) steps (assuming a square array).

Comment: so, what will be the worst case scenario in this case? i'm assuming that the worst case is when element is not present

Comment: @Dinara: yes, you're right. Also, my logic was slightly flawed, seems the worst case would be x+y.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I'm confused, in your answer you say it's O(n) but here you're saying it's O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: @Godwin: In my answer, I state that I assume that `n` is the length of one side of the array, not the total number of elements.

Comment: ou, i'm confused), so finally order of provided solution is O(n) or O(sqrt(n))? And ,@Godwin please  could you explain why it x+y in worst case?(assuming that we have square two dimensional array)? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dinara: It depends on whether you define *n* as the total number of elements, or the length of each side of the array.

Comment: @Dinara: seeing this (which I didn't at first either) is fairly trivial. Just look at what the loop is doing, it's counting through x and y with no other option at each step.